# Can I rename the Journey_name and DE name of the API Entry source journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have done a TYPO in the naming convention of the API Entry based journey. And now I have to rename-the Journey Name and DE-Name, can I perform this without stopping/creating new version?

Comment: I Noticed that I am able to re-name the DE, but NOT possible for Journey_name!

Comment: You're trying to rename the Journey or the EventDefinitionKey for the API event?

Comment: Name of the Journey in journey builder!

Comment: No. You'd need to create a new version of the Journey in order to rename it.

Comment: Agreed, thanks @Macca